# Multi-factor Authentication prompts

Tags: ms-access, sharepoint, vba, multi-factor-authentication

I have an Access (2010, 2013, 2016) application sent to users throughout the world. This application downloads data from a Sharepoint-based ticketing system for use offline.

The Sharepoint system we use recently implemented a requirement for multi-factor authentication in order to connect. However, the MS Access prompt for credentials doesn't include the MFA argument. How can we pass MFA credentials from Microsoft Access to Sharepoint?

Users on the company VPN can connect just fine. In order to get on the VPN, one must enter their MFA credentials, so Sharepoint uses that. However, if users aren't on the VPN (some contractors do not have access), they aren't prompted for the MFA token and cannnot connect. However, if they go directly to the Sharepoint URL, they can login via MFA just fine - but the access application doesn't recognize that MFA connection/credientials even if the Sharepoint site is open.

Users do not have admin rights to their machines and cannot download third-part applications to circumvent this issue. The Access application is using DAO to connect to the Sharepoint server in VBA.

We must refresh the link to the sharepoint list before downloading, otherwise those outside the VPN have their connection timeout. Code is below to illustrate:

```
Dim tdf As DAO.TableDef
Dim userName As String, myPassword As String
Dim thisDB As DAO.Database
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
DoCmd.Hourglass True

Set thisDB = CurrentDb
 RemoveInvalidRelationships "Linked_FSE_List_Field_Service_Request"

 For Each tdf In CurrentDb.TableDefs

If Left(tdf.Connect, 3) = "ACE" Then
        tdf.RefreshLink
    End If
Next
```

For clarity purposes: this question is about how to pass authentication parameters to Sharepoint.

Comment: Is this the actual code you have attempted to accomplish your requirement? What happens - error message, wrong results, nothing?

Comment: If you're on the VPN, the tdf.RefreshLink line pops up an authentication window, asking for username/password. If you're not on the VPN, nothing pops up, and the connection is not made to sharepoint.

I'd like to know how to pass the authentication parameters to Sharepoint to enable those off VPN have access.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass authentication credentials in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22149169/how-to-pass-authentication-credentials-in-vba)