# Bypass authentication in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am using below code to bypass authentication from Excel to some report in internet which from this thread

[How to pass authentication credentials in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22149169/how-to-pass-authentication-credentials-in-vba)

```
Dim response As String

With CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
  .Open "GET", address, false, username, password
  .Send
  response = .responseText
End With

Msgbox response
```

this works in Windows 7 with Excel 2012. When I get new laptop which is Win 10 with Excel 2016, it keep pop up the window to enter username and password, which defined in the code previous.

Does anyone have idea what should be done for Win 10 with Excel 2016 to bypass the authentication? Thanks!

Comment: There was never a MS Excel 2012. You may want to check which Excel version you had. You can refer to [THIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Excel)

Comment: Do you have the relevant information in the variables?

Comment: @SiddharthRout Yes, you are right, it was Excel 2013.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav that's all I use to bypass the authentication before. I connect to external data source using a .iqy file. Same code used to be working, while keep prompting up Windows Security window for username and password.